# passing output of a netcat command to a variable or piping through read utility

Tags: bash, netcat

The output of the netcat command `nc - dvzw1 8.8.8.8 443` does not appear to behave in the way that output from other commands have predictably worked when stored in a variable or piped through the read utility.

1. Storing the nc cmd output to a variable `cmd_output=$(nc -dvzw1 8.8.8.8 443)` produces an empty variable. Same result without the v switch. Other cmds can be stored to variable (ls -a, pwd, date).
2. Piping the nc output to the read utility as below writes nothing to the file. Same result without the v switch.

```
nc -dvzw1 8.8.8.8 443 | while read line ; do echo -e "$now $line" ; done >> ~/vpn.log
```

The 'while read echo' pipe has worked with another command. I can also redirect the nc command output directly to file ( ie: without piping to 'while read echo').

Answer (score 7):

```
> nc -dvzw1 8.8.8.8 443
Connection to 8.8.8.8 443 port [tcp/https] succeeded!
```

The `Connection to 8.8.8.8 443 port [tcp/https] succeeded!` is written into stderr, standard error. The `$( ... )` command substitution captures standard output of a command.

You can ex. redirect standard error to standard output: `nc -dvzw1 8.8.8.8 443 2>&1`.

If you just want to check if the `nc` command succeeded, just check it's exit status, ex. using if `if nc -dvzw1 8.8.8.8 443 2>/dev/null; then echo "Succeeded"; else echo "failed"; fi` or by inspecting `$?`.

Comment: `Connection to 8.8.8.8 443 port [tcp/https] succeeded` reports success. It has an exit status of 0.                                         `nc: connect to 8.8.8.8 port 443 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress` reports error or failure. It has an exit status of 1.  Stderr

Comment: ...is for errors and diagnostics as far as I understand it. Are they both stderr?